# HTML: Base64 image displaying/copying with wrong height

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

So, basically I have a simple base64 image like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rm5c8o1t

My problem is that it only displays the upper half of it. If I simply add this to the img tag:

```
style="height: 300px;"
```

it will display as I want it too. The issue now is when I try to copy it (right-click, copy image), it doesn't work at all on Firefox, and only the upper half part of it is copied on Chrome/Opera.

The image is generated in Javascript from SVG as follows:

```
var svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg[0]);
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(svgData);
```

svg being a jQuery element, which displays as intended when trying to append it to the document. The reason why I need to have an actual image instead of just using the svg tag is that I want users to be able to copy the image easily. The app is basically an editor that contains thousands of possible background/foreground combinations, so I can't simply convert this SVG to an image with an external tool.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: More complete jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Lv5sa0

Comment: I would guess that there's an issue with the original svg data - such as the drawing board size? Are you able to put a more complete jsfiddle which includes an example of a generated SVG, then includes the conversion code?

Comment: Sure, I just added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't assign dimensions of your SVG via style. Assign them via actual attributes:

```
<svg id="svg" width="320" height="320" >
```

Then the resulting image will be created of correct size and copy/paste will work as well.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p2Lv5sa0/2/**

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!

I also learned that using .width(x) and .height(x) on a jquery element will change the style, and not the actual width and height attributes.